# Need to make my android application modify an xml file on a server, and it needs to save the changes after modification

Tags: android, xml

How can I make my application do this? It would need to parse the xml then modify it then save it once it finishes the process.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Rough algorithm:

1. Open up a HTTP Connection and download the XML file.
2. Use Simple XML to parse the XML file into your objects.
3. Modify the objects that were parsed in so that it has been changed to what you want it to be.
4. Write it back out to XML using the Simple XML Library again.
5. Send the file back to the Server and tell the server that it is an updated version.

The [Simple library is here](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) and [I wrote a blog post on how to use it in android](http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/).

Comment: do i need to set up special permissions on the server?

Comment: Well how do you want to access the XML file? Privately? Publically? Based on a user or an API key? Essentially what is your situation? I cannot be any more specific without knowing more information.

Comment: any way we can get into contact privately? It's a public website, and I'm not very good at this.